# How can I shortcut an expression who's repeating?

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I need help to know if can i use #definie for commands in batch or anything else like shortcuts
for example i have `del "C:\Games"` so i definie "C:\Games" as {output}

so I wrote:

```
@echo off   
#Definie output "C:\Games"
Del "{output}"
```

But it didn't work for me
  my problem is, when i create a script, many things are repeating and sometimes i get error
this is a part of the script

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q0j8.png

as u can see in the pic,  the  yellow is repeating many times
can u suggest me a shortcut, i mean like i difinie the yellow as {output} and i write the yellow just one time 
and then i replace all the yellows with {output}

This is what I've tried later in another exemple

```
@echo off

From=[C:\Users\Easynote-TE69HW\Desktop\Ectended fromto\From]

del /f /q from
```

Comment: Open a command prompt window, enter `set /?` and read the usage information.

Comment: Once you've followed the above advice, please repeat the process for both `del /?` and `rd /?`, _since one deletes files and the other removes directories_.

Comment: Oh thnank's that worked but the folders inside cannot b deleted
only files

Comment: if you read my previous comment, you'd note that one `Del`etes files and the other, `R`emoves `D`irectories. If you want further assistance, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53379336/edit), to include the code you've now written, complete with an explanation of what happens which differs from your intent.

Comment: Yes i saw what did u say about `rd` but i did not how should i put it, please check the end of the question above to see what did i write, thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "From=C:\Users\Easynote-TE69HW\Desktop\Ectended fromto\From"
rd /s /q %from%
```

The second line sets (defines) a variable named `From`. (Note: variable names are case insensitive)
the third line uses that variable (`%from%`) with the `RD` command (Remvove Directory).
The switch `/s` works recursive (delete all subdirectories), `/q` doesn't ask for confirmation.

See the helpfile for any command with the switch `/?` (e.g. `set /?` or `rd /?`).

Also [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) should be extremely helpful (a complete list of possible commands and their description)

Comment: Thank that helped me a lot but what i need is to delete all the folders and files inside `From` not the `From` itself

Comment: Is it an option to just recreate it? `md "%from%"`